# как в css сделать данное задание при использовании свойства display flex Не получается разделить блоки между картинкой сверху и снизу

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Как отделить верхний блок от нижнего?]***

```css
<style>
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        h4 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        p {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .cont {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .border {
            border: 2px solid gray;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 20px;
        }
    </style>
```

```html
<body>
        <h2>What do I have in my fridge</h2>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="border">
                <div><img src="Food_C247-128.png" alt="">
                    <p>Pepper</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C240-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Apple</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C217-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Chesse</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C245-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Corn</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C239-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Mushroom</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border">
                <div><img src="Food_C238-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Garlic</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C225-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Beef</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C205-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Fish</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C203-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Eggs</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C235-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Coriander</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h4>...that's all...</h4>
    </body>
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно просто указать ширину или минимальную ширину или максимальную:

```
        .border {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: calc(20% - 10px);
            border: 2px solid gray;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin:  5px;
        }
```

```css
        h2 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        h4 {
            text-align: center;
        }

        p {
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .cont {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .border {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: calc(20% - 10px);
            border: 2px solid gray;
            border-radius: 25px;
            padding: 0px;
            margin:  5px;
        }
```

```html
        <h2>What do I have in my fridge</h2>
        <div class="cont">
            <div class="border">
                <div><img src="Food_C247-128.png" alt="">
                    <p>Pepper</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C240-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Apple</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C217-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Chesse</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C245-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Corn</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C239-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Mushroom</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border">
                <div><img src="Food_C238-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Garlic</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C225-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Beef</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C205-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Fish</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C203-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Eggs</p>
            </div>
            <div class="border"><img src="Food_C235-128.png" alt="">
                <p>Coriander</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <h4>...that's all...</h4>
```